# Is there a Relationship Between Multi-Valued Logic and n-Satisfiability?

Tags: logic, soft-question, computer-science, computational-complexity

Is binary (Boolean) logic related at all to the two-satisfiability problem?

And is ternary logic related in some way to the three-satisfiability problem?

Would it follow then that if one were to work in a ternary logical system, computations would be much “harder”? (Assuming P does not equal NP?)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-valued_logic

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no connection of the kind you seem to be imagining.

2-SAT and 3-SAT are both about satisfiability in ordinary two-valued logic. They differ in which shapes of formulas you can ask to have satisfied, but *satisfying* that formula is a matter of ordinary true/false logic in both cases.

The "canonical" satisfiability problem in computational complexity is 3-SAT, about two-valued logic and formulas with at most three atoms per clause.

2-SAT is a *restricted*, particularly easy, case of that.

Comment: So there's no way to rewrite binary statements into ternary logical statements the way there is to rewrite 2 variable formulas into three variable formulas?